# Model classes in ASP.NET Core and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an api call that returns the following response:

```
{
    "MenModel":[{"Id":"123"}],
    "WomenModel":[{"Id":"456"}],
    "AuthenticationResponse":0,
    "InstanceId":"14976bc0-28ac-4a57-9dfe-93ff0dd39d65"
}
```

I need to update the response such that MenModel and WomenModel are included in a Model as follows:

```
{
    "Model": {
        "MenModel[{"Id":"123"}],
        "WomenModel":[{"Id":"456"}]
    },
    "AuthenticationResponse":0,
    "InstanceId":"14976bc0-28ac-4a57-9dfe-93ff0dd39d65"
}
```

How do I create parent model and include child models within it?

Existing code:

Response class:

```
public class GetValuesResponse 
{
    public GetWomenModel WomenModel { get; set; }
    public GetMenModel MenModel { get; set; }

    public GetValuesResponse()
    {
    }
}
```

Handler class:

```
protected async Task<GetValuesResponse> XYZ(GetValuesRequest request)
{
    var response = new GetValuesResponse();
    var women = await _databaseWomenRepository.SelectWomenAsync();
    var men = await _databaseAppSubmittersRepository.SelectMenAsync();
    response.WomenModel = new GetWomenModel(women);
    response.MenModel = new GetMenModel(men);
    return response;
}
```

Model class:

```
public class GetWomenModel : List<WomenModel>
{
    public GetWomenModel(IEnumerable<Women> entities)
    {
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            var id = new WomenModel(entity);
            this.Add(id);
        }
    }
}

public class WomenModel
{
    public WomenModel(Women entity)
    {
        Id = entity.Id;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add another class that acts as the parent model to MenModel and WomenModel:

```
public class PeopleModel
{
    public GetWomenModel WomenModel { get; set; }
    public GetMenModel MenModel { get; set; }
}
```

Then your GetValuesResponse class becomes:

```
public class GetValuesResponse
{
    public PeopleModel Model { get; set; }

    public GetValuesResponse()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3693060 - You are welcome! If this helped to solve your problem, an accepted answer would be appreciated. Good luck with your project!

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking the little checkmark underneath the number of upvotes/downvotes.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did! Thank you.